# problem with memcpy'ing from shared memory in boost.interprocess

Tags: c++, shared-memory, boost-interprocess

This is driving me wild with frustration. I am just trying to create a shared memory buffer class that uses in shared memory created through Boost.Interprocess where I can read/store data. I wrote the following to test the functionality

```
#include <boost/interprocess/shared_memory_object.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/mapped_region.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace boost::interprocess;

int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) {
    shared_memory_object::remove( "MyName" );
    // Create a shared memory object
    shared_memory_object shm ( create_only, "MyName", read_write );
    // Set size for the shared memory region
    shm.truncate(1000);
    // Map the whole shared memory in this process
    mapped_region region(shm, read_write);
    // Get pointer to the beginning of the mapped shared memory region
    int* start_ptr;
    start_ptr = static_cast<int*>(region.get_address());

    // Write data into the buffer
    int* write_ptr = start_ptr;
    for( int i= 0; i<10; i++ ) {
        cout << "Write data: " << i << endl;
        memcpy( write_ptr, &i, sizeof(int) );
        write_ptr++;
    }

    // Read data from the buffer
    int* read_ptr = start_ptr;
    int* data;
    for( int i= 0; i<10; i++ ) {
        memcpy( data, read_ptr, sizeof(int) );
        cout << "Read data: " << *data << endl;
        read_ptr++;
    }

    shared_memory_object::remove( "MyName" );
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this, it writes the data OK, but segfaults on the first `memcpy` in the read loop. gdb says the following:

> Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
>   Reason: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at address: 0x0000000000000000
>   0x00007fffffe007c5 in __memcpy ()
>
> (gdb) where
>
> #0  0x00007fffffe007c5 in __memcpy ()
>   #1  0x0000000100000e45 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fff5fbff9d0) at try.cpp:36

The functionality is so simple, I don't know what I'm missing. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`data` isn't being set to point at anything. (Make sure the program is being compiled with all warnings enabled.) It looks like it shouldn't be a pointer anyway.

The second loop should perhaps be:

```
int* read_ptr = start_ptr;
int data;
for( int i= 0; i<10; i++ ) {
    memcpy( &data, read_ptr, sizeof(int) );
    cout << "Read data: " << data << endl;
    read_ptr++;
}
```

Comment: (blush), that sure makes me feel dense! I'm suffering from TIQL (temporary IQ loss) it seems (I *hope* it's temporary).
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can't test it here because I don't have `boost` available but I a have guess. In this **[example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/interprocess/sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.html#interprocess.sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.sharedmemory.shared_memory_a_simple_example)**,
 the `shared_memory_object` object is first used to write with a flag `create_only`.

```
shared_memory_object shm (create_only, "MySharedMemory", read_write);
```

Then it is read with a second `shared_memory_object` object with a flag `open_only`:

```
shared_memory_object shm (open_only, "MySharedMemory", read_only);
```

It seems you have to change your `shared_memory_object` to a proper flag.